# Display sample download in list view

Tags: magento

I have a storefront that has just downloadable products. In my design, all products are displayed in list view. On that list view i want to have a button to play the sample audio file from the downloads.

I'm having an issue retrieving that sample file. I just want to play the first sample attached to a product.

Has anyone done this , or would know how to accomplish this ? Using the same code to retrieve a sample file from the product page doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this:

```
<?php if ( $_links = $_product->getDownloadableLinks() ) {
    foreach ($_links as $_link) {
        // Do what you want with $_link
        //Mage::log($_link->getData());
    }
?>
```